# How to understand an intent when calling startActivity()?

Tags: android

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed.-- quoted from android document. It's an "intention" to do an action--quoted from best answer in Stackoverflow.

Given code as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I can not tell what action this "intent" wants. Until I see startActivity(), I understand it wants to start the Activity, not kill it(if it can). Why not just startActivity(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class) ?

Explicitly let me create an Intent without an action, and the document and almost all the explaination tell me that "intent" is intent to do something, really confusing me. Please help me here.

---

I think the reason it bothers me here is why not use a common function like fulfillMyIntent() after I put an action and all imformation needed by the action. Of course, I can accept that we use any type in an abstract way. But usually I use an object either totally abstract(empty) or totally concrete, not half concrete(like an intent without an action). Possiblly I should try to feel more comfortable of half concrete object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not tell what action this "intent" wants.

Also from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

> It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity,

So "this `intent` wants" to start an `Activity`.

> Why not just startActivity(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class) ?

You can almost do this but it would look more like

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class))
```

`Intent` is still a class which has `constructors`, one of which you need to call when using it. Doing it this way is fine but you can do it the first way you show in your question so you can add `extras`, `data`, etc... to it before making the method call to `startActivity()`.

> Explicitly let me create an Intent without an action

Then what would be the purpose of an `Intent`? Why do you want to create one if you aren't going to perform some action with it? Create a variable then. If I am going to create the "Intent" to go to the store but I don't actually intend to go to the store then why would I say that I intend to in the first place? I would instead say that I am going to eat an apple and not go to the store. That may seem a little abstract but I'm not sure what you want the `Intent` for if you are going to do anything with it.